# If the water flows at a pace of 10 cubic meters per hour, how much electricity can a micro hydropower system produce?

Tags: electrical-engineering

The diameter of the recipient through which the water is passing is 10 cm.

LE: There is no height involved, but depth, as a matter of fact. Let's assume that there is a 100 meters deep well, which has the capacity to lift water from the bottom to the surface at a pace of 10 cubic metres per hour.

[image: A diagram of the well with and without kinetic mechanism]

Comment: Any height involved?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, so we will expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Explain your reasoning and show all of your work. Then, if you get stuck, ask a **specific** question.

Comment: Ha, no, is not a homework assignment. I don't have engineering background so I thought I should formulate it as best as possible to understand people what I ask.

Comment: There is no height involved, but depth, as a matter of fact. Let's assume that there is a 100 meters deep well, which has the capacity to lift water from the bottom to the surface at a pace of 10 metric cubic per hour.

Comment: The well is replacing the water extracted with a regular pump. So is just underground water moving up naturally, at a pace of 10 cubic meters per hour.

Comment: I'll add clarifications, @AJN, but is different than your suggestion.

Comment: A diagram of the situation would be nice. Where are you planning to install the hydropower system since the water is flowing in from the soil all around the well. Hydropower systems usually require water to flow from one direction.

Comment: I am confused about the word "produce", as it is equivalent to "generate", but "lift" the water from a deep well "consumes" power, is your question concerning "the power from the inflow to lift the free water surface at such speed"? Please show a sketch to clarify.

Comment: @r13: The way I'm interpreting this is it's a 10 cm diameter drill hole that has punctured a pressurized aquifer & water is rising up the hole to the surface.

Comment: I added a sketch, hopefully describes a bit better the circumstances.

Comment: (1) Why is your wheel at the bottom of the well? Why not put it just below the pump? (2) Why is the pump 10 m deep when you could just have it at the surface since water is flowing up the pipe? (3) You would probably avoid the chain and use a submersible generator, axis vertical, with a propeller like that of a ship to capture the energy.

Comment: I don't see any benefit of the wheel. It stirs and spins the surrounding water, causing turbulence that may impede water flow. The water rises largely depending on the internal pressure of the aquifer.

Comment: P = V* I  .   The rest is cosmetic.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** *this question was answered prior to the diagram being included. This assumed, the 10 cm diameter drill hole had punctured a pressurized aquifer & water was rising up the hole to the surface under aquifer pressure.*

A quick back of the envelope calculation.

The flow rate is 10 m<sup>3</sup>/h. This is the equivalent of 10 t/h, or 10,000 kg/h, or $\frac{10}{3600}$ m<sup>3</sup>/s.

Using the equation,

$Q \ = \ va$

Where $Q$ is flow rate, $v$ is velocity and $a$ is area of flow.

The velocity of the water exiting the hole is

$v \ = \ \frac{4Q}{\pi D^2}$ = $\frac{4}{360\pi (0.1)^2}$ = $0.3537 \ m/s$

The kinetic energy of the water is,

$E_k \ = \ \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ = $\frac{10,000(0.3537)^2}{2}$ = $625.439 \ J$

This occurs every second, so the power available, ignoring friction and other losses is $625 \ W$.

Comment: Your answer seems to be what I was expecting to find out.  
However, I'm not qualified to evaluate the calculations.  

I added a sketch. Is your result the same?

Comment: @GeorgeI.: As I wrote in my comment to R13 & my subsequent edit to the answer my assumption was hole had punctured a pressurized aquifer & water was rising to the surface as a result of aquifer pressure. My answer is the theoretical maximum power available, ignoring losses & inefficiencies. The turbine wheel, as you have indicated in the diagram, after your edit, introduces larger inefficiencies thus any energy recovered would be less.

Comment: I concur with Fred's last point, the turbine wheel offers no benefit. I think if it is a propeller spinning horizontally may help the situation.

Comment: I added the turbine as an example of one way of converting water pressure to electricity. The theoretical maximum power available is very good as reference for alternative ways of converting water pressure to electricity.

Answer (score 0):

With the diagram included, I think that the introduction of the turbine will finally appear as an increase in the power draw on the pump.

So, the electric power that you get out of this will effectively be supplied by the electric power that you originally input to the pump. i.e. *not-free*.

Comment: That's true. I can think of a dozen alternatives to that turbine, but a reference amount of energy would help to determine the expectations.

Comment: The other answer covers that part, I think. But still, even if one uses a mechanism other than a turbine, it will all finally appear as additional power draw on the pump, since the flow is created / sustained by the pump. @GeorgeI.